# .Net5 Azure Function | Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am implementing a scenario where I have created Azure ServiceBus singleton client in Azure Function (v3, .net v5). Within my Azure function code, I am creating `ServiceBusMessageBatch` and then I'm trying to add some messages in the batch and finally a `Task` into `List<Task>` but as soon as I start my azure function (or after 1-2 runs) I'm starting to get `Error: System.InvalidOperationException: The message batch is currently being used in communication with the Service Bus service; messages may not be added until the active operation is complete.` Error.

Below is my code

```
int batchSize = int.Parse(configuration["batchSize"]) > 0 ? int.Parse(configuration["batchSize"]) : 1;
var SBSender = serviceBusClient.CreateSender(configuration["QueueName"]);
using ServiceBusMessageBatch messageBatch = await SBSender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();
List<Task> addQueues = new();
try
{
    if (MyMessages.Count > 0)
    {
        int messageIndex = 0;
        for (int count = 0; count < MyMessages.Count; count += batchSize)
        {;
            BatchMessage bMessage = new();

            for (; messageIndex < count + batchSize && messageIndex < MyMessagesCount; messageIndex += 1)
                bMessage.Add(MyMessages[messageIndex]);

            if (!messageBatch.TryAddMessage(new ServiceBusMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bMessage))))
                throw new Exception($"Message is too large");
        }
        addQueues.Add(SBSender.SendMessagesAsync(messageBatch));
    }
}
```

I am using `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` (v7.6) instead of bindings is because `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus` doesn't support native ServiceBus types.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

The error is the result of attempting to use the same `ServiceBusMessageBatch` instance for multiple calls to `SendMessagesAsync`.

The part of your code where you are doing so doesn't appear to be included, but you'll want to ensure that you're using only one sender instance and creating a new batch for each call to `SendMessagesAsync`.